# Meaning of この延長線上にこそ、

Tags: meaning, expressions, conjunctions

Does `X。この延長線上にこそ、Y。` have the same meaning as `XなのでY` ?

Context: `今回、時間の制約が大変厳しい状況にありますが、[...]自動的なチェックのしくみを実現したいと考えます。この延長線上にこそ、新しい世代のより低コストな技術を安定的に評価できる体制が実現可能となります。`

Answer (score 2):

With your context, `X。この延長線上にこそ、Y。` means 'only if (we have) X, (we can achieve) Y'. This is different from `XなのでY` which means 'because of'.